# Getting warning "The following references to java symbols could not be resolved." when running Fortify maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, fortify

I am using sca-maven-plugin to scan a multi module maven project. Unfortunately I ran into the the following warning while executing translate

> [warning]: The following references to java functions could not be
>   resolved. These functions may be part of classes that could not be
>   found, or there may be a type error at the call site of the given
>   function relative to the function declaration. Please ensure the java
>   source code can be compiled by a java compiler.

The code can be compiled by a java compiler, which leads me to believe that something is wrong with the classpath. Despite this I remain unconvinced due to the fact that as I understand it Maven handles the classpath and passes it to sourceanalyzer. How do I solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check the maven compiler plugin you are using . May be you are using some code which compiles with the higher version of java.

Also makes sure all the dependencies are added properly and the jars are apart of classpath.

Please share your pom.xml

Comment: I run the following maven commandline com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin:sca-maven-plugin:4.20:clean
com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin:sca-maven-plugin:4.20:translate -Dfortify.sca.toplevel.artifactId=xxx -Dfortify.sca.sourceanalyzer.executable=D:\Fortify\bin\sourceanalyzer
-Dfortify.sca.source.version=1.7
-Dfortify.sca.buildId=xxx
-Dfortify.sca.verbose=true
com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin:sca-maven-plugin:4.20:scan` from Jenkins and my compiler is at version 3.5.1 and source/target set to 1.7 Unfortunately I can not share my pom but I am happy to answer questions.

Comment: Modify the classpath supplied to Fortify to include the jar files which contain the listed classes.

Comment: through property -Dfortify.sca.cp?